# Apps store settings/cache (the Android directory) on SD card even though it's not where they reside?

Tags: settings, sd-card, storage, youtube, cache

Phone: Galaxy Note 4, Android 5.1.1

I would expect apps to store their settings/cache in a place where they reside, i.e. if app is on MMC the settings should be on MMC and if it's SD they should be on SD (one would hope!).

However I observe that after a reboot - with an empty SD card plugged in (and to my horror) - a lot of applications (YouTube for example) create directories and files on the SD card (under Android directory), typically most of them being empty. What I want is to confine my entire apps storage to MMC and I'll keep my pictures and movies on SD.

Is there a reason why Android/Samsung is preventing me from doing that? Is there a setting I forgot to turn on/off?

Cheers in advance for any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Settings of the apps are stored in their data folder and not in where they reside. The data folders of apps can be found under /data/data, a directory that a non-root user can't access.

What you see are just some additional data folders some apps tend to create.